# Finding and combining acronyms in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, twitter

I am trying to process some tweets, and I am trying to split up certain terms in the tweets as follows :

```
word : DailyRX 
final_word : Daily R X

word : AdeleOfficial
final_word : Adele Official

word : HMV 
final_word : H M V

word : EPPGroup 
final_word : E P P Group

word : BBCBreaking 
final_word : B B C Breaking

word : BBCNews 
final_word : B B C News
```

EDIT --

Using @user2486495's solution, I was able to get the output I wanted as above. Here is the solution :

```
newlist = [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', word) if a]
replacement=""
for term in listnew:
    replacement+=term+" "
tweet = tweet.replace(word,replacement)
```

Now I am trying to think of a way to do the following --

Ideally, I would want "BBCBreaking" to break up as "BBC Breaking", but I couldn't think of a way to do this. So I first broke it up by upper case characters as described above, and then I am trying to find all acronyms separated by spaces (i.e. "B B C") and combine them into one word without spaces (i.e. "BBC"). Is there a way to do this using regex?

EDIT 2 --

Solved using @Hugh's answer below, which also takes care of numbers e.g. "Oscars2013" --> "Oscars 2013"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import re

splitter = re.compile('[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[^A-Za-z \t\r\n]+').findall
fix_tweet = lambda t: ' '.join(splitter(t))
```

then

```
fix_tweet('AdeleOfficial')    # -> 'Adele Official'
fix_tweet('EPPGroup')         # -> 'EPP Group'
```

Explanation of the regex: it matches

- `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])`    one or more capital letters, NOT followed by a lowercase letter
- `[A-Z]?[a-z]+`       0 or 1 capital letters followed by one or more lowercase letters
- `[^A-Za-z \t\r\n]+`  one or more non-alpha, non-whitespace characters

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot! I see now that I should learn more about regex.

Comment: This even takes care of numbers i.e. 'Oscars2013' --> 'Oscars 2013'

Answer (score 1):

The method split() returns a list of all the words in the string, using str as the separator (splits on all whitespace if left unspecified), optionally limiting the number of splits to num.

```
str.split(str=" ", num=string.count(str))
```

**Parameters**

str -- This is any delimeter, by default it is space.

num -- this is number of lines to be made.

**Return Value**

This method returns a list of lines.

**For example**

```
[a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]
```

**Output**

```
['Mg', u'S', u'O', u'4']
```

Comment: I know about using split(), but how should I use it to split the string at every capital letter?

Comment: [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks a lot! I didn't think it would be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `"\B[A-Z]"` and replace with `" $0"` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yC6qM6)